# Getting Access Denied while cloning using git clone command

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-clone, git-for-windows

I am getting the below error while cloning my repository: please suggest

```
Gurudas@Gurudas MINGW64 /e/Python/Python Programs (master)
$ git clone https://github.com/Anu1996rag/Python_Basics.git
Cloning into 'Python_Basics'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Anu1996rag/Python_Basics.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly. Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The `getaddrinfo` part of the error message seems like it's pointing to a DNS problem. Can you `ping github.com` from your terminal/shell? I'm not familiar with `MINGW64` and perhaps you should add that tag to the question in case it's related.

Comment: @karmakaze : am unable to ping github.com

C:\Users\Gurudas>ping github.com

Pinging github.com [13.234.210.38] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 13.234.210.38:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

can you please let me know how to resolve this ?

Comment: Sorry I don't much about MINGW64 at all, I mostly use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) when on Windows 10. I suggest changing the question title to say something about git-bash/MINGW64 and DNS to get the right people to see this.

Answer (score 2):

`MINGW64` means a `git bash` session on Windows.

Check your `git config http.proxy` output as well as your `echo $HTTP_PROXY` output, to check if you have any proxy defined.

Check also if an SSH URL would work (provided you have [configured first an SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) , using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM`, and added the [public one `id_rsa.pub` to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account))

```
git clone git@gihub.com:Anu1996rag/Python_Basics
```

Comment: If you cannot ping github.com, this is not surprising indeed.

Comment: I had the same problem, I tried several solutions until I found out that in my case it was the firewall. Mine was the "Free Firewall", I noticed that even authorizing the software and connections it was still not possible to have a connection to the remote repository. I disabled it and it didn't solve it, only when I uninstalled it that the problem was solved and I was able to use Git normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case solved this by updating git version from `2.41.0` to `2.42.0` on Windows. Try updating maybe it's work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the firewall, turned it off, and tried to sign out from GitHub on my local machine, but all these steps didn't help me.

Just restarted my PC and now everything works perfectly :)