# fatal: unable to access <link> getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: git, git-for-windows

When I type: `git push origin master`

Error :

```bash
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<github-username>/<repository-name>.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

What do I do?

This is git being used on a windows machine

Comment: Start a new terminal and type `git config --global --unset-all https.proxy` and try again.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/59517290/720999

Comment: We're talking about using Git on Windows, are we?

Comment: Yes, we are talking about using git on windows

Comment: The suggested method didn't work. So I created a new Github account, added SSH key and now it works well. Although any lead regarding the previous one would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Access Denied while cloning using git clone command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517290/getting-access-denied-while-cloning-using-git-clone-command)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem, I tried several solutions until I found out that in my case it was the firewall. Mine was the "Free Firewall", I noticed that even authorizing the software and connections it was still not possible to have a connection to the remote repository. I disabled it and it didn't solve it, only when I uninstalled it that the problem was solved and I was able to use Git normally.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the firewall - I'm using windows defender firewall, and the way my machine is set up on the domain regularly causes me firewall-related issues. In this case (and many others) restarting the windows defender firewall solved the problem completely.

Comment: I hit this issue when I had been playing with the startup type for the Windows Defender Firewall service in Windows. I found that if the firewall was configured as Manual start, it would repro this problem. If configured as Automatic start, the problem went away. This startup value can be adjusted via the Registry (not configurable via services.msc).

Comment: I suddenly experienced `fatal: unable to access <link> getaddrinfo() thread failed to start` after `git` commands had worked for a long time. It coincided with some network-level errors I started hitting in another process that was doing heavy I/O. My stupid-simple soln was to plug my ethernet cable in and out. That worked :)

Comment: I have to add here that @alexandreiolov's solution of replugging the ethernet cable worked for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

Same issue on my machine (git version 2.28.0.windows.1).
The problem seems to be related to DNS resolution of HTTP-requests:

This was my original remote url:

```
git remote set-url origin http://<FQDN>:<http_port>/<repository>.git
```

With the same result as in the question:

```
$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'http://<FQDN>:<http_port>/<repository>.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

When changing the URL to the resolved IP:

```
$ ahost <FQDN>
<FQDN>                               <IP>

$ git remote set-url origin http://<IP>:<http_port>/<repository>.git
```

Git connects without issue:

```
$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

Also, when using SSH instead of HTTP there is no issue with the resolution:

```
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://<username>@<FQDN>:<ssh_port>/<repository>.git
$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

Curl also doesn't work in my MINGW64 environment:

```
$ ahost www.google.com
www.google.com                          172.217.2.100
    
$ adig www.google.com
id: 64322
flags: qr rd ra
opcode: QUERY
rcode: NOERROR
Questions:
        www.google.com .                A
Answers:
        www.google.com .        49      A       172.217.2.100
NS records:
Additional records:


$ curl www.google.com -v
* getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

* Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have any antivirus or firewall installed into the system, either turn off the git access or uninstall completely and restart. I faced the same issue and uninstalled the firewall. It worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does this answer add that wasn't in the accepted answer?

Comment: Truely if you are using firewall then allow the git program.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved for me when a vpn service was running in the background by finishing its task in Windows task manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git remote set-url origin http://<IP>:<http_port>/<repository>.git
or
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://<username>@<FQDN>:<ssh_port>/<repository>.git
```

My problem is solved using above the way !!

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly got this on a Gitlab CI server in a job that builds a Docker image.

```
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from geo.mirror.pkgbuild.com : getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

After a lot of digging around (eventually running `strace docker build` in the CI job), I discovered the issue is caused by a blocked syscall called `clone3`.

```
clone3({flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, child_tid=0x7f6cb634c990, parent_tid=0x7f6cb634c990, exit_signal=0, stack=0x7f6cb5b4c000, stack_size=0x7fff80, tls=0x7f6cb634c6c0}, 88) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

A bit of searching later, I [discovered](https://medium.com/nttlabs/ubuntu-21-10-and-fedora-35-do-not-work-on-docker-20-10-9-1cd439d9921) that

> Docker injects the SCMP_ACT_ERRNO(EPERM) rule for all syscalls that are unknown to Docker. So, when glibc attempts to call clone3() , the kernel raises EPERM (“Operation not permitted”) error according to Docker’s seccomp profile.

I found that Docker images prior to `20.10.10` are affected by this and my Gitlab runner was configured to use `20.10.8` - so the solution in my case was to reconfigure the runner to use `20.10.10` images.

Comment: Oh this is so dumb but correct as well. I had docker running on wsl2 and it kept failing to push the branch. I stopped the service on WSL2 and suddently everything worked normally.
Running strace on my docker instance tho however revealed a different error from yours:
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, data={u32=3625202520, u64=139684551603032}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Answer (score 0):

```
fatal: unable to access <link> getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

this error showing it means your pc firewall not allowing to proceed this kind of operation
so just disable it from your System and also from your anti-virus and use your git normally.
hope it will work for you.