# Why does git fail with "getaddrinfo() thread failed to start" when in a subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

My Python code calls `subprocess.Popen()` with a command:

```
 git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android
```

I call my Python code from the command line Terminal within PyCharm, on Windows 11.

It fails to run getaddrinfo():

```
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

I run the exact same command directly in the same terminal, and it runs perfectly.

Hmmm... That sounds like it can't get network access... and the answers to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911649/fatal-unable-to-access-link-getaddrinfo-thread-failed-to-start) all agree to check the firewall.

I only have Microsoft Defender Firewall, and I tried turning off all of the Domain network, Private Network and Public Network firewalls. (My router is still protecting me.) It makes no difference.

I would have thought the firewall, even if it were on, would be paying attention to `git.exe` (I have confirmed they are finding the same exe.) and wouldn't trigger on one and not the other.

Where should I look next? Any clues what might be blocking git from accessing the network when running in a Python subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess did not contain the environment variable `SystemRoot` (which typically points to `C:\WINDOWS`).

If you run `git` without that environment variable set, it gives that same error.