# Fatal: unable to access getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: git-for-windows

This was working 1 month back. But recently it is showing following error when I try to either sync or pull from repository.

- Error: *git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase "origin" fatal: unable to access getaddrinfo() thread failed to start*
- Also I have verified that I am not able to connect github.com. I mean when pinged to github.com it returns no response

I have viewed following threads. Answers / comments given in these threads are not working for me.

*[Getting Access Denied while cloning using git clone command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517290/getting-access-denied-while-cloning-using-git-clone-command)

[fatal: unable to access <link> getaddrinfo() thread failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911649/fatal-unable-to-access-link-getaddrinfo-thread-failed-to-start)*

- I am using Windows 10 Professional version and Visual Studio 2019
  Community Edition.
- I am accessing GIT repository from https://xxxx.visaulstudio.com/
- Repository URL is HTTPS and not SSH

I have tried following solutions :

1. Delete credentials from windows credential manager
2. Uninstall GIT for Windows and installed latest one (2.26.2.1)
3. Removed GIT folder from location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
   Explorer"
4. Verified Anti Virus (Quick Heal). There is no record or setting for blocking particular domain
   5  There is no issue of firewall.

but none of these are working.

I saw following link and same is reported by multiple users. It seems to be issue with compatibility of Git Credential Manager with Azure Devops authentication

https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues

Help is really appreciated.